# Finding the largest square in an n * n grid

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization

I have a problem where I have to find the largest square in an n * n grid. 
e.g.

```
. . . . .
. # . # .
. # . . .
. # . # .
. # . . .
```

where the biggest square would be 3 by 3 in the bottom corner.
I am supposed to return the most steps someone could take before turning right so that they can repeat this infinitely without hitting a wall "#" or going outside the n * n square which is why the output is one less that the width/length of the square.

My code loops through the grid left to right, top to bottom looking for vertices that face down and to the right. Once it finds one it then looks for the biggest possible vertex facing up and to the right and when it finds that checks all four sides to see whether or not they are made up or `.`. This code works in under 1 second for me on anything around n = 100, however I need it to run at 1 second for n = 500. Any tips on how I can speed this up?

```
import sys
input = sys.stdin.readline

n = int(input())
maze = [list(input()) for _ in range(n)]

squares = 0
for r in range(n - 1):
    for c in range(n - 1):
        if maze[r][c] == '.' and maze[r][c + 1] == '.' and maze[r + 1]        [c] == '.':
            sides = []
            for i in range(min(n - r - 1, n - c - 1), -1, -1):
                if maze[r + i][c + i] == '.' and maze[r + i][c + i - 1] == '.' and maze[r + i - 1][c + i] == '.':
                    sides = i
                    if maze[r][c : c + sides] == ['.'] * sides and maze[r + sides][c : c + sides] == ['.'] * sides:
                        a = True
                        for j in range(sides):
                            if maze[r + j][c] != '.' or maze[r + j][c + sides] != '.':
                                a = False
                        if a and sides > squares:
                            squares = sides
                            break
            if squares == n - 1:
                break
print(squares)
```

Comment: How about a O(n^3) algorithm? I think it still can fit in 1s for n = 500

Comment: why not the 3x3 square on the upper right corner?

Comment: Either would work, I had to edit the example to make it format properly and didnt see that.

Comment: @MSeifert thats what its supposed to output. The actual question asks for the most number of steps that can be taken before turning 90 degrees right. This is the same as finding the biggest square just the output is one less.

Comment: What can a 4x4 square look like? What about a 5x5 square?

Comment: You said the goal is to "return the most steps someone could take before turning RIGHT".  Is it okay to turn left?  Can you go over steps you already used?  That is can you go counter clockwise around a square forever?

Comment: @RootTwo Turning left is fine and the point is that you repeat that infinitely so yes you would go over steps you already have

Comment: @Yunis Does any of the answers help you? Please feel free to ask for clarification if anything is unclear :)

Comment: @shole Yes caenyon's answer made it clear. I used his idea to write my own and it worked, thank you.

Comment: no problem :) be sure to accept answer that helped you the most

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's an interesting problem. I tried out some things and ended up with this implementation which is `O(n^3)`. I commented the code so that you can follow the idea hopefully. There's still room for speed improvements, but this version already does the job (e.g. with maze size 500x500):

```
Finished after 0.708 seconds.
Result: 112581 squares found, maximum square (x=13, y=270, size=18).
```

This is the source code (Python 3):

```
import random
import pprint
import time

# small sample maze
maze = ['.....',
        '...#.',
        '.#...',
        '.#.#.',
        '.#...']
# convert to boolean maze
maze_bin = [[True if cell == '.' else False for cell in line] for line in maze]

# uncomment to generate a random maze
# maze_size = 500
# threshold = 0.2
# maze_bin = [[1 if random.random() >= threshold else 0 for _ in range(maze_size)] for _ in range(maze_size)]

# take start time
t1 = time.time()

# rotate the maze (first column becomes first row, first row becomes first column)
maze_bin_rot = [[maze_bin[i][j] for i in range(len(maze_bin))] for j in range(len(maze_bin[0]))]

# horizontal_lengths is a two-dimensional list that contains the number of possible steps to the right for every cell.
horizontal_lengths = []
for line in maze_bin:
    num = 0
    line_lengths = []
    for i in reversed(line):
        line_lengths.append(i*num)
        num = i * (num + i)
    horizontal_lengths.append(tuple(reversed(line_lengths)))

# vertical_lengths is a two-dimensional list that contains the number of possible steps to the bottom for every cell.
vertical_lengths_rot = []
for line in maze_bin_rot:
    num = 0
    line_lengths = []
    for i in reversed(line):
        line_lengths.append(i*num)
        num = i * (num + i)
    vertical_lengths_rot.append(tuple(reversed(line_lengths)))
# do the rotation again to be back in normal coordinates
vertical_lengths = [[vertical_lengths_rot[i][j] for i in range(len(vertical_lengths_rot))] for j in range(len(vertical_lengths_rot[0]))]

# calculate the maximum size of a square that has it's upper left corner at (x, y).
# this is the minimum of the possible steps to the right and to the bottom.
max_possible_square = []
for y in range(len(maze_bin)):
    line = []
    for x in range(len(maze_bin[0])):
        line.append(min(horizontal_lengths[y][x], vertical_lengths[y][x]))
    max_possible_square.append(line)

# search for squares
results = []
max_size_square = (-1, -1, -1)
for y in range(len(max_possible_square)):
    for x in range(len(max_possible_square[0])):
        # start with maximum possible size and decrease size until a square is found.
        for size in reversed(range(1, max_possible_square[y][x]+1)):
            # look at the upper right (x+size,y) and bottom left corner (x,y+size).
            # if it's possible to make at least size steps to the right from the bottom left corner
            # and at least size steps to the bottom from the upper right corner, this is a valid square.
            if horizontal_lengths[y+size][x] >= size and vertical_lengths[y][x+size] >= size:
                results.append((x, y, size+1))
                if size+1 > max_size_square[2]:
                    max_size_square = (x, y, size+1)
                # break after the the largest square with upper left corner (x,y) has been found.
                break

t2 = time.time()

# comment this print section if you use larger grids
print('Maze:')
pprint.pprint(maze_bin)
print('\n')
print('Horizontal possible steps:')
pprint.pprint(horizontal_lengths)
print('\n')
print('Vertical possible steps:')
pprint.pprint(vertical_lengths)
print('\n')
print('Maximum possible size of square:')
pprint.pprint(max_possible_square)
print('\n')
print('Results:')
for square in results:
    print('Square: x={}, y={}, size={}'.format(*square))
print('\n')

# final results
print('Finished after {:.3f} seconds.'.format(t2-t1))
print('Result: {} squares found, maximum square (x={}, y={}, size={}).'.format(len(results), *max_size_square))
```

I hope this is what you were looking for. If you have any questions, just leave a comment below ;)

Answer (score 3):

I can think of a `O(n^3)` algorithm as follows:

1. Precompute 4 arrays: `top[][], bottom[][], left[][], right[][]`, each stores the maximum length of a direction that you can go from `(i,j)`
2. For each `(i,j)` , use it as a square's bottom left corner, for each its diagonal points `(i-1, j+1), (i-2, j+2)`...etc., test if those points can be used as the square's top right corner. Store the maximum square side in the process

For step 1, all 4 arrays can be precomputed in `O(n^2)`

For step 2, as we loop through all `(i,j)`, and for each `(i,j)` we have to see at most all diagonal points which is at most `n` of them, total we get `O(n^3)`

The test in step 2 can be done in `O(1)` using the 4 precomputed arrays, simply check if the 4 corners of the "possible squares" can be joined by checking the corresponding directions (top, bottom, left, right)

---

Of course, there are many minor things which can be done to speed up, for example:

In step 2, for each `(i,j)`, only check for diagonal points which is in the range `[current_maximum_diagonal_found ... max(right[i][j], top[i][j])]`

Update `current_maximum_diagonal_found` along the whole algorithm, so that we hope for some `(i,j)`, we do not need to check whole `n` diagonal points.

But strictly speaking, it is still `O(n^3)`, but as far as I know it should be able to run in 1 second for `n~500`

Comment: ok i had the same idea (see my post), but actually it's enough to have two precomputed arrays. if you start from the top left corner for example, you just need to know how far you can go to the right and to the bottom from each point.

Comment: Yea you are absolutely right, I was just roughly providing an simple idea without thinking too much...

Answer (score 0):

If we do not want to enumerate all results, one optimization that may be worth considering is the following. It's based on the strategy - "do not proceed further with this cell if it can not lead to the optimal solution"

```
for y in range(possible_y_value):
    for x in range(possible_x_value):
        # We are ready to process cell identified by (x,y).
        # Check if max_possible_square_length at this cell is greater than size of best_result seen so far. If so, proceed further, otherwise skip this cell
        if max_possible_square[y][x]+1 > best_result.size:
            # proceed further with the inner most for loop
            ....
```

Even from within the inner most for loop, we can break out of the loop at the iteration when it falls below the best_result's size seen so far